# Is jmeter insert the data in real time?

Tags: insert

Currently i am using j meter.I have a test plan order like
Login,Add Patient(After login).After executing the test plan successfully,i checked the application whether new patient is added or not.Yes,Its added in the application when the test plan(HTTP) is successful.Now i have two questions

- Data is added in the application,Whether its correct or not?
- Suppose i don't want to insert the data in the application means what
  i have to do.Is there any configuration?.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to automatically check whether patient was added or not.
2. If you considering a form of [negative testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_test) i.e.

   - ensure that patient will NOT be added if wrong credentials are provided
   - ensure that patient will NOT be added if logged in user doesn't have permission to add patients

   You can use the same Response Assertion but with reverse condition.

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on how to conditionally set pass and/or fail criteria basing on request results.